# Ignoring child touch, and receive them on parent widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a tree as below:

```
GestureDetector
  Container
    Column
      Row
        Expanded
          LinearProgressIndicator
```

and `GestureDetector` doesn't recognize `LinearProgressIndicator` taps, i also wrapped `LinearProgressIndicator` with `IgnorePointer` but did not make a difference.

What's wrong with `LinearProgressIndicator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just fixed by setting `behavior` attribute of `GestureDetector` by `HitTestBehavior.opaque`.